# Best Algorithm to randomly generate a number that is divisible by N

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Is there a better agorithm to do the following?

I am trying to generate 50 random numbers that are divisible by 7. I then select one of those 50 at random & return that number.

**Is there a more efficient/better way to randomly generate numbers that are divisible by 7? Is there a better way I could code/do this?**

```
    unsigned int generateRandomNumberDivisibleByN( unsigned int n, unsigned int num=10 )
    {
        // Post: Generate many different random numbers that are divisible by n, then randomly select one of
        //       of those numbers to return.

        unsigned int potentialNums[num];

        for (int i=0, j=2; i<num; i++, j=rand()%INT_MAX)
        {
            potentialNums[i] = j*n;
        }

        return potentialNums[ rand()%num ]; // should this be rand()%(num-1) so it never returns an invalid array index?
    }
```

Comment: Is there really a benefit over just `rand() * n` ? Is generating an array of random numbers and then picking one at random really going to improve anything ?

Comment: The easiest way I know to generate a random number divisible by 7 is `7*rand()`. If you have more specific needs, you need to state clearly the requirements...

Comment: You should be careful about overflow: when `j > INT_MAX / 7`, `7*j` will overflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why can't you just do this?

```
return (rand() % MAX) * 7;
```

It does almost the same thing.

Where `MAX` is small enough to avoid overflow during the multiplication by 7. Which you can define as:

```
const MAX = INT_MAX / 7;
```

Or if you want it to be fast, you can do something like:

```
return (rand() & 0xff) * 7;
```

Comment: The % or & operation will skew the distribution, though `& 0xFF` shouldn't skew if RAND_MAX is a power of two.

Comment: @harold: I think `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to be a power of two.

Comment: @MooingDuck the only guarantee I can find is that it must be at least 32767

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way to randomly generate a number divisible by 7 is to generate a random number and then multiply it by 7.

```
return ( rand() % ( INT_MAX / 7 ) ) * 7
```

Comment: The % operation there will skew the distribution. Why not just divide by 7 and then multiply by 7? That also skews but it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Why generate a bunch of random numbers, then choose one of them at random?  You have the core idea already:  generate a random number and multiply it by 7.  The `potentialNums` array doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 0):

To make this much faster first use the fast random generation function [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry) this should make the actual process of creating randoms much faster,

Next, you can multiply the random by 7 and it will always be a multiple of 7, however, if this multiplication causes an overflow of the int (which with randoms is likely) you can always take a mask of the first few bits and multiply them.

e.g.

`randomNumber = (generatedRandom & 0x00FFFFFF) * 7`